# How to loop through an object to form to form conditions

Tags: javascript

I have an object as shown below:

```
{
    Condition0: "5"
    Condition1: "6"
    LogicalOperator0: "&&"
    Operator0: "<"
    Operator1: "!="
    Question0: "How do you rate our services?"
    Question1: "How likely are you to recommend our services to others?"
}
```

I would like to arrange it to form a condition as

```
Question0 Operator0 Condition0 LogicalOperator0 Question1 Operator1 Condition1
```

So that the result forms Comparison Operators that appears like below:

```
How do you rate our services? < 5 && How likely are you to recommend our services to others? != 6
```

Anyone please assist to achieve this in JS.

Comment: Why don't you group your data by question? Like `[{Question, Operator...}, {Question, Operator}]`. Then it's extra easy. Now you have to parse key to know how to group elements and it's extra hard work

Comment: You are required to join object keys so use concat operator `+` (https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/string-concat) like `o.Question0 + o.Operator0 + o.Condition0 + o.LogicalOperator0 + o.Question1 + o.Operator1 + o.Condition1` where `o` is your actual object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a nested loop for the properties and numerical part and collect all parts in an array.

```js
let data = { Condition0: "5", Condition1: "6", LogicalOperator0: "&&", Operator0: "<", Operator1: "!=", Question0: "How do you rate our services?", Question1: "How likely are you to recommend our services to others?" },
    keys = ['Question', 'Operator', 'Condition', 'LogicalOperator'],
    result = [],
    i = 0;

outer: while (true) {
    for (const part of keys) {
        const key = `${part}${i}`;
        if (!(key in data)) break outer;
        result.push(data[key]);
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(result.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the order of the displayed property into an array and manipulate that one

```js
const obj = {
  Condition0: '5',
  Condition1: '6',
  LogicalOperator0: '&&',
  Operator0: '<',
  Operator1: '!=',
  Question0: 'How do you rate our services?',
  Question1: 'How likely are you to recommend our services to others?'
}

const order = [
  'Question0',
  'Operator0',
  'Condition0',
  'LogicalOperator0',
  'Question1',
  'Operator1',
  'Condition1'
]

const res = order.map(prop => obj[prop]).join(' ')

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hello... this problem with the const order is I am not sure how many loops there are. Could be from say `Question0` to `Question23`

Answer (score 0):

Assign the object to a variable and access it from there:

```js
var someName = {
    Condition0: "5"
    Condition1: "6"
    LogicalOperator0: "&&"
    Operator0: "<"
    Operator1: "!="
    Question0: "How do you rate our services?"
    Question1: "How likely are you to recommend our services to others?"
}
//Accessing the values would look like:
//someName.question0 + somename.operator0 + somename.condition0...
```

If you looped through the object, it would only be accessed in the order in which it has been created. You seem to need to access it in a different order.